# Optimize Multiline Pipe to Awk in Bash Function

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have this function:

```
field_get() {
  while read data; do
    echo $data | awk -F ';' -v number=$1 '{print $number}'
  done
}
```

which can be used like this:

```
cat filename | field_get 1
```

in order to extract the first field from some piped in input. This works but I'm iterating on each line and it's slower than expected.

Does anybody know how to avoid this iteration?

I tried to use:

```
stdin=$(cat)
echo $stdin | awk -F ';' -v number=$1 '{print $number}'
```

but the line breaks get lost and it treats all the stdin as a single line.

IMPORTANT: I need to pipe in the input because in general I DO NOT have just to cat a file. Assume that the file is multiline, the problem is that actually. I know I can use "awk something filename" but that won't help me.

Comment: because I don't want to type the awk command every time, that's the main point of functions, having shortcuts.

Comment: Actually a job for `cut`: `cut -d\; -f1 somefile`. `awk` is not necessary.

Comment: It's your misuse of `echo` that's stripping the newlines. Always quote your variables unless you have a specific reason not to - `echo "$stdin"`, not `echo $stdin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use either `stdin` or `file`

```
field_get() {
  awk -F ';' -v number="$1" '{print $number}' "${2:-/dev/stdin}"
}
```

**Test Results:**

```
$ field_get() {
   awk -F ';' -v number="$1" '{print $number}' "${2:-/dev/stdin}"
}

$ echo '1;2;3;4' >testfile

$ field_get 3 testfile 
3

$ echo '1;2;3;4' | field_get 2
2
```

Comment: thanks, it works with a multiline pipe, that's what I needed :) very nice way to fallback to stdin if there's no file as input argument, didn't think about that.

Answer (score 4):

Just lose the `while`. Awk is a while loop in itself:

```
field_get() {
  awk -F ';' -v number=$1 '{print $number}'
}
$ echo 1\;2\;3 | field_get 2
2
```

**Update**:

Not sure what you mean by your comment on multiline pipe and file but:

```
$ cat foo
1;2
3;4
$ cat foo | field_get 1
1
3
```

Comment: the pipe is multiline, so you have to pipe in a multiline file.

Comment: ok, sorry, you're right it works :) I'll leave the other one as accepted answer because there's also the option to use a filename as argument. thanks!

Comment: Sure, it was a nice addition.

Answer (score 3):

No need to use a `while` loop and then `awk`. `awk` itself can read the input file. Where `$1` is the argument passed to your script.

```
cat script.ksh
awk -v field="$1" '{print $field}' Input_file

./script.ksh 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for the `cut` command:

```
cut -d';' -f1 somefile
```